# How to 'cut&paste' elements between xml nodes in Scala?

Tags: xml, scala

I want to pull all the  elements out of an older file (the 'good' one) and replace the  elements in a newer file (the 'bad' one). These files are the same content (with minor editorial changes) and the same format.

I'm new to scala and having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around how to do this swap.

```
import scala.xml.{NodeSeq, XML, Node}
import scala.xml.transform._

object cloneImages {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {

    val articleImageNodes = getImageNodes("data/articles_en-ca_20151022.xml")   // Seq[(id: String, nodes: NodeSeq)]
    val articleIds = articleImageNodes.map{ case (id: String, nodes ) => id }
    val badXml = XML.load("data/articles_en-ca_20151116.xml")     

    // produce 'goodXML' node by 
        // 1) removing all <media> child nodes
        // 2) inserting corresponding <media> node from articleImageNodes

    println("done")
  }

  /**
    * Pulls correct image nodes (with id string) from xml file.  (There 
    * may be multiple image nodes.)
    * @return
    */
  def getImageNodes( file: String): Seq[(String, NodeSeq)] = {

    val goodXML = XML.load( file )
    val articles = goodXML \ "contentitem"
    for (
      a <- articles;
      id <- a.attribute("id").map { _.toString() };
      imgNodes <- Option( a \\ "media" )
    ) yield {
      (id,imgNodes)
    }

  }
}
```

The xml follows this general format:

```
<content>
  <contentitem type="article" id="ST00427">
    <metadata>
      <media photographer="" src="https://..." />
      <canonicalurl>http://...</canonicalurl>
      ...
    </metadata>
    <article>...</article>
    ...
  </contentitem>
  ...
</content>
```

Answer (score 2):

I did it with rewrite rules. So, let's we have a bad XML:

```
val oldXml = <content>
  <contentitem type="article" id="ST00427">
    <metadata>
      <media photographer="" src="https://..." />
      <media photographer="" src="https://..." />
      <media photographer="" src="https://..." />
      <media photographer="" src="https://..." />
      <canonicalurl>http://...</canonicalurl>
    </metadata>
    <article></article>
  </contentitem>
</content>
```

and good part

```
val goodPart = <metadata>
  <media photographer="" src="https://1" />
  <media photographer="" src="https://2" />
  <media photographer="" src="https://3" />
  <media photographer="" src="https://4" />
  <canonicalurl>http://5</canonicalurl>
</metadata>
```

Then I wrote two Rewrite Rules:

Rule that removes all media tags:

```
private def removeMedia() = new RewriteRule {
  override def transform(n: Node): Seq[Node] = n match {
     case e: Elem if e.label == "media" => NodeSeq.Empty
     case v => v
   }
}
```

Rule that inserts new media tags:

```
private def insertNewMedia(goodMedia: NodeSeq) = new RewriteRule {
  override def transform(n: Node): Seq[Node] = n match {
    case Elem(pref, "metadata", attrs, scope, child @ _*) =>
      Elem(pref, "metadata", attrs, scope, true, goodMedia ++: child : _*)
    case v => v
  }
}
```

Last spet is to apply rewrite rules with `RuleTransformer`

```
val cleanXml = new RuleTransformer(removeMedia()).transform(oldXml)
val goodXml = new RuleTransformer(insertNewMedia(goodPart \ "media")).transform(cleanXml)
```

result is:

```
<content>
  <contentitem type="article" id="ST00427">
    <metadata><media photographer="" src="https://1"/><media photographer="" src="https://2"/><media photographer="" src="https://3"/><media photographer="" src="https://4"/>                                        
      <canonicalurl>http://...</canonicalurl>
    </metadata>
    <article></article>
  </contentitem>
</content>
```